# Knockout ko.mapping.fromJSON not updating

Tags: knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a complex object with nested properties that switch from being null to being an actual populated object. I can map everything just fine the first time through ko.mapping.fromJSON. But when an event causes a subsequent mapping to occur where properties become null and others get values the mapping goes crazy:

http://jsfiddle.net/L5sgW/51

When the "Update!" button is clicked the alert('1') fires and "Test2" is displayed. However, click "Update!" again and alert('2') fires but the text does not alter. Any ideas?

html:

```
<p> <span>Name:</span>
    <span data-bind="text: IntroData ? IntroData.Name : TempData.Name"></span>
    <button id="update" data-bind="click: Update">Update!</button>
</p>
```

javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var me = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, me);

    me.Update = function () {
        if (me.Index() == '0' || me.Index() == '2') {
            alert('1');
            ko.mapping.fromJS(stuff2, {}, me);
        } else {
            alert('2');
            ko.mapping.fromJS(stuff3, {}, me);
        }
    };

    return me;
};

var stuff = {
    Index: '0',
    IntroData: {
        Name: 'Test'
    },
    TempData: null

};

var stuff2 = {
    Index: '1',
    IntroData: {
        Name: 'Test2'
    },
    TempData: {
        Name: 'Temp2'
    }
};

var stuff3 = {
    Index: '2',
    IntroData: null,
    TempData: {
        Name: 'Temp3'
    }
};

window.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(new ViewModel(stuff));
ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've provided different shapes for IntroData and TempData in stuff and stuff3.

1/ When ko.mapping.fromJS interprets TempData: null, it will produce a ko.observable(null).
2/ When ko.mapping.fromJS interprets TempData: { Name: 'Temp3' } it will produce an Object with a member 'Name' which is a ko.observable('Temp3').

For example, stuff:

```
    > ko.mapping.fromJS({ Index: '0', IntroData: { Name: 'Test' }, TempData: null }, {});

    Object {Index: function, IntroData: Object, TempData: function, __ko_mapping__: Object}
      Index: function observable() {
      IntroData: Object
        Name: function observable() {
        __proto__: Object
      TempData: function observable() {
      __ko_mapping__: Object
      __proto__: Object
```

And stuff2:

```
    > ko.mapping.fromJS({ Index: '1', IntroData: { Name: 'Test2' }, TempData: { Name: 'Temp2' } }, {});

    Object {Index: function, IntroData: Object, TempData: Object, __ko_mapping__: Object}
      Index: function observable() {
      IntroData: Object
        Name: function observable() {
        __proto__: Object
      TempData: Object
        Name: function observable() {
        __proto__: Object
      __ko_mapping__: Object
      __proto__: Object
```

Note that TempData is a function (observable) in stuff's mapped object, but an object with a sub-property 'Name' in stuff2's mapped object.

So why does this not work?  Your binding specifies:

```
    text: IntroData ? IntroData.Name : TempData.Name
```

The problem is IntroData is *never null*, and always "truthy".  (It's either an object, or an observable.  In either case, not null.)  So what to do?  Well, we can make the definition shape similar, so that ko.mapping updates the values correctly.  I modified your binding to be:

```
    text: IntroData.Name() ? IntroData.Name : TempData.Name
```

And changed your object definitions to be:

```
    var stuff = {
        Index: '0',
        IntroData: {
            Name: 'Test'
        },
        TempData: {
            Name: null
        }
    };

    var stuff2 = {
        Index: '1',
        IntroData: {
            Name: 'Test2'
        },
        TempData: {
            Name: 'Temp2'
        }
    };

    var stuff3 = {
        Index: '2',
        IntroData: {
            Name: null
        },
        TempData: {
            Name: 'Temp3'
        }
    };
```

And you'll see that your update button now shows changes per click.  It looks like you're trying to cycle through stuff -> stuff2 -> stuff3.  The code doesn't do that, but you shouldn't find it hard to make that happen.  :-)